# Regex to match given text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this following string

```
</p><drupal-entity data-view-mode="oembed_display"></drupal-entity><p><strong>Designer Crush:</strong></p><drupal-entity data-view-mode="oembed_display"></drupal-entity><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

pattern is

```
<drupal-entity((?!<drupal-entity).)*?><\/drupal-entity><p>&nbsp;<\/p>
```

which is matching fine, but having some extra character at
as another group `"`
and i just want this string to be matched

```
<drupal-entity data-view-mode="oembed_display"></drupal-entity><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Ex https://regex101.com/r/Aeqxxy/1

Comment: So the regex you're using is `<drupal-entity((?!<drupal-entity).)*?><\/drupal-entity><p>&nbsp;<\/p>`, and what you want it to produce is `<drupal-entity data-view-mode="oembed_display"></drupal-entity><p>&nbsp;</p>`, but what is it that you're currently getting back as output instead? Can you post the exact incorrect output you're seeing now?

Comment: Have you got a bracket in the wrong place?? drupal-entity).*?)

Comment: Example here https://regex101.com/r/Aeqxxy/1

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/p0Vx7q/1

Comment: If you just don't want to capture the `"` then do as Wiktor has suggested and add `?:` just inside the capture group.  If this is not what you want, please clarify your question.  ...and ping Wiktor after you do so that he can post an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you solution worked for me, so if you can post ur answer, i can accept. Thanks.

Comment: @mks I added an answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa: It is true that negated character classes work faster than lookaround-based tempered greedy token, but they match rather different strings.

Comment: @mickmackusa: See [OP regex](https://regex101.com/r/Aeqxxy/3) vs. [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/Aeqxxy/4).

Answer (score 1):

If there are no tags within the drupal-entity tags, then my pattern will provide a highly efficient match.  However, my pattern cannot be trusted if there is so much as a possibility of a `>` between the drupal tags.

So I am saying, my pattern is compromise on accuracy for speed, but I am only making this compromise because the sample input text doesn't show an inner tags -- so I am running with an assumption.

Pattern: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Aeqxxy/2))

```
@<drupal-entity[^>]+></drupal-entity><p>&nbsp;</p>@
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about how to avoid additional items in the match array. Note that these items with IDs from 1 and up are added whenever a pattern contains a **capturing group**. Capturing groups are made with a pair of unescaped parentheses.

Your pattern contains `((?!<drupal-entity).)*?` [**tempered greedy token**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) where you used `(...)` thus creating a capturing group. This pattern matches any char (`.`) *and captures it into Group 1* (that creates an additional item) that is not a starting point for a `<drupal-entity` substring, and matches 0+ of such chars, as few as possible (thus, it is not the same pattern @mickmackusa suggests, it will match up to the first `></drupal-entity><p>&nbsp;</p>` substring. **It means it won't handle nested tags**, just be warned.

**If possible, use an HTML parser**.

To solve the issue, you need to replace the capturing group with a [**non-capturing**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) one, and it will already yield the desired results: `(?:(?!<drupal-entity).)*?` (note the `?:` added after the initial `(`).

Comment: I would just like to offer that using a negated character class to match the remaining portion of the opening `<drupal` tag, you can save a fair amount of steps while maintaining the true accuracy of Wiktor's method.  Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Aeqxxy/5)

Comment: @mickmackusa If we are talking optimizations, you may even consider [`<drupal-entity[^>]*>[^<]*(?:<(?!drupal-entity)[^<]*+)*?</drupal-entity><p>&nbsp;</p>`](https://regex101.com/r/Aeqxxy/6).